# "Cannot open database requested by the login. The login failed." When the database name is incorrect

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception, connection-string

I'm writing some code at work to test the connectivity to an SQL Server database. Here is the code I am working with:

```
public bool TestSQLServerConnectivity(
            string serverAddress,
            int? serverPort,
            string databaseName,
            string userName,
            string password,
            out Exception exception)
{
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder() { 
                InitialCatalog = databaseName
            };

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName) &&
        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
        connectionStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

    connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = serverPort.HasValue
                                               ? $"{serverAddress}, {serverPort.Value}"
                                               : serverAddress;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
    {
        connectionStringBuilder.UserID = userName;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
    {
        connectionStringBuilder.Password = password;
    }

    exception = null;

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString()))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            return true;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            exception = ex;

            if (ex.State != 0 && ex.InnerException == null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm aware of the issue in the following snippet of code, and I will be checking for the authentication method instead of what I'm currently doing, but this works for testing and it is not the issue:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName) &&
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
     connectionStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
```

The issue is that I'm trying to connect to SQL Server by sending a WRONG database name. I'm expecting it to throw an exception saying that the database does not exist or something of the sort. I'm confused why it is instead throwing an exception saying

> Cannot open database requested by the login. The login failed

Things to note:

1. I am not sending values in for username and password, so it's using Integrated Security (Windows authentication).
2. The database exists on a different machine in our lab, and this code is being called from another machine in our lab too (vhsm lab, but I don't think that matters).
3. When I send the correct database name, the connection does not throw any exceptions.

Additionally, I'm also confused about the `State` property of the `SqlException`. In the aforementioned exception thrown, the State is 1. I looked this up, and apparently 1 stands for warning. How is this a warning?

I have a hunch that MAYBE it is trying to  create the database since it doesn't exist and maybe it doesn't have the authority to do so? I may be completely wrong though.

Why is this error being thrown instead of a "database does not exist" error? And why is the State 1? Any guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: _I may be completely wrong though._ You are - databases are not created by a login attempt. And the error is clear - there is no reason to expect a different error.

Comment: But I want people watching Sql server to see this, it's relevant, no?

Comment: Yes the sql server tag is relevant if that is the DBMS you are using. But initially you tagged with both mysql and sql server. They are NOT the same thing.

Comment: SMor, I see. So this is the expected error when a database does not exist. Can I distinguish that from failed login fordenied access for example? Or will that throw the same error

Comment: Also, why is the "State" of the SqlException 1?

Comment: The state you see outside of SQL Server is always 1, for obscurity reasons (don't help a potential attacker by spelling out for them why their attack failed). Authorized users can see the actual state (and other details) in SQL Server's errorlog, which can be helpful when the message isn't enough. I detail most states here: [Troubleshooting Error 18456](https://sqlblog.org/2020/07/28/troubleshooting-error-18456).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @AaronBertrand. I'm sorry for dragging this out though, but I glanced at the article you mentioned. Our SQL Server version is 15.0.2000.5, which is SQL Server 2019. In the article you mentioned that State 1 was present in the log for all failures prior to SQL Server 2005. Did you mean in the errorlog for SQL Server? Which means that for 2019 State 1 is always shown outside of SQL Server but was fixed in the errorlogs to show the correct state as you just mentioned?

Comment: Yes, that means in the errorlog for SQL Server in versions prior to SQL Server 2005. You could always _check_ the errorlog on your SQL Server 2019 instance to confirm what I'm talking about (the article was written years ago so the behavior before 2005 isn't even relevant to this conversation, or pretty much any conversation today).

Comment: Thank makes a lot of sense. Thank you! It was gonna drive me mad trying to figure out why every case gave a state of 1 :D